# ArcGIS 10 Add Field to Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-10.0

In ArcGIS 10, is there a way to add a field to a feature class even if it currently contains data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Field ArcGIS 10
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Adding_fields/005s0000000v000000/

Comment: Thanks.  I had been trying to do it through ArcCatalog, but this did what I needed.

Comment: Is there any way to modify an existing field name (not an alias)?

Comment: Modifying existing field names is at top of ArcGIS Desktop Ideas that users would like to see Esri implement: http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=ArcGIS+Desktop&sort=top

Answer (score 6):

To do this programmatically, use [IClass.AddField](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AddField_Method/0025000000vp000000/).  (Do NOT use IFieldsEdit.AddField on an existing dataset).

Answer (score 2):

In Python, using the ArcPy site package, you'd use

arcpy.AddField_management(.....)

You cannot modify the actual field name of an existing field.  I would LOVE to be able to do that, but even if they implement it, I bet it'll be similar to renaming in SQL.  That is, the net effect is a renamed field, but the underlying operation is: make new field with new field name, copy contents from old field, drop old field name.