# Creating coordinates from beg and end points on a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, linear-referencing

Is it possible to create WGS-1984 coordinates from the start and end points along a line segment?

The line features were created using linear referencing but now I need to create lat and long coordinates for the start and end of each line segment.

Here is some of the data from the attribute table:

```
OBJECTID *  CORRIDOR_CODE_RB    FRFPOST TRFPOST Shape *
   9        C001976N               0      0.76  Polyline M
   10       C002068N             0.432    0.984 Polyline M
   11       C002111N               0      0.432 Polyline M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data Management Tools\Features\Feature Vertices to Points` from Toolbox with BOTH_ENDS point type option should be able to help you extracting the endpoints for line segments.

Calculate coordinates for those endpoints afterwards by going to attributes table, creating two new fields and Calculating Geometry on them to add Lat and Lon.

Comment: That's an excellent process. Unfortunately I do not have the proper license to use Feature Vertices to Points. I'll contact admin and see if I can get that lifted. Ill get back to you as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: I'll need to work on getting my license changed to Advanced, but I have been working with the GIS admin and she says this process will work. So thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Add new](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/arcgis-10-add-field-to-feature-class) fields to the table of you lines, xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd. Use type = Double

Right click on them one by one and pick relevant option from the list:

[image]

alternatively just type it in:

[image]

using one that seems relevant from:

```
!SHAPE!.firstPoint.X
!SHAPE!.firstPoint.Y
!SHAPE!.lastPoint.X
!SHAPE!.lastPoint.Y
```

Comment: That does work well for that particular field of shape_length. But how would I get the other coordinates, such as the latitude? In my case I converted shape_length into longitude, or the x coordinate. I would need the lat and long for the start and the end. The method above works well, but this method seems promising as well if I can get the other coordinates.

Comment: After reading your post and comments I think you should wait for advanced license or even better install ArcGis PRO

Comment: Yes I will soon be able to switch up to Advanced license when needed. There aren't a lot of the advanced licenses floating around this place so I can use temporarily as needed. But thanks for the input that's a cool way of turning shape length into coordinates.

Comment: Ok, being a nice person works. Sometimes. I am disarmed. It was a joke because a) Maxims's solution is NOT what you want unless you know how to bring values from newly created point table back to lines table b) shape_length has nothing to do with my solution. I'll update my answer shortly. BTW if you want to say thank click arrow up next to my answer

Comment: I was able to make good use of the outputted table by adding x, y coordinates. I then used SQL to rearrange the coordinates to what I wanted and all is well. I don't think I have the reputation high enough to upvote your answer. Ive already tried.

Comment: No worries than. glad it works